# Squid proxy with ncsa_auth

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm trying to setup a squid proxy with ncsa_auth but I cant find ncsa_auth on my system

I installed squid with apt-get install squid

As i understand it it should be installed with squid, anyone know of another way to install it or why it wasn't installed in the first place?

```
$ dpkg -L squid
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/squid
/usr/share/doc/squid/copyright
/usr/share/doc/squid/README
/usr/share/doc/squid/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Comment: Maybe you should try `squid3` instead `squid`.

Comment: squid installs squid3 i looked throe new programs that was going to be installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong package with `dpkg -L` there. The `squid` package is a transitional package, which only depends on `squid3` which does contain the `ncsa_auth` program.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, you where about a minute faster so... :)

Answer (score 7):

`squid` is a "dummy transitional package from squid to squid3". Probably `squid3` is already installed in your system, as `squid` depends on `squid3`.

`ncsa_auth` is located in `/usr/lib/squid3/`.

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem. In my situation the name of the file is "basic_ncsa_auth", and this simpe difference makes a mess hehe.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Today is a good day to get the habit to add * at every file search :-) `find / -name *ncsa_auth*`. Thank you.